# Docker multi stage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I came across this [example](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/examples/python3-requirements/Dockerfile#L12) . Here they made a 3 stage build. Is it necessary to have a 2nd stage (build-venv) ?

Is it mentioned that having it can have an advantage of "Build the virtualenv as a separate step: Only re-execute this step when requirements.txt changes". But I was under assumption that docker is intelligent enough to not build the image layer if it is not changed.

Is there any difference between

original Dockerimage

```
# Build a virtualenv using the appropriate Debian release
# * Install python3-venv for the built-in Python3 venv module (not installed by default)
# * Install gcc libpython3-dev to compile C Python modules
# * In the virtualenv: Update pip setuputils and wheel to support building new packages
FROM debian:11-slim AS build
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --yes python3-venv gcc libpython3-dev && \
    python3 -m venv /venv && \
    /venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

# Build the virtualenv as a separate step: Only re-execute this step when requirements.txt changes
FROM build AS build-venv
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN /venv/bin/pip install --disable-pip-version-check -r /requirements.txt

# Copy the virtualenv into a distroless image
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11
COPY --from=build-venv /venv /venv
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["/venv/bin/python3", "psutil_example.py"]
```

And (2nd stage removed)

```
# Build a virtualenv using the appropriate Debian release
# * Install python3-venv for the built-in Python3 venv module (not installed by default)
# * Install gcc libpython3-dev to compile C Python modules
# * In the virtualenv: Update pip setuputils and wheel to support building new packages
FROM debian:11-slim AS build
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --yes python3-venv gcc libpython3-dev && \
    python3 -m venv /venv && \
    /venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN /venv/bin/pip install --disable-pip-version-check -r /requirements.txt

# Copy the virtualenv into a distroless image
FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11
COPY --from=build-venv /venv /venv
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["/venv/bin/python3", "psutil_example.py"]
```

Any build time advantage of one over the other ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect both paths to be identical.  Arguably the first path would let you `docker build --target` do get an image that contained the C toolchain and an empty virtual environment, but I wouldn't expect this to be a frequent use case.

More generally, there's not really a benefit to splitting a build into multiple stages but having the second stage start `FROM` the first one.  If your Dockerfile has

```
FROM ... AS a
COPY ...
RUN ...

FROM a
RUN ...
```

then you will get the same image out at the end whether there are two build stages or just one (deleting the second `FROM` line).  Build-time layer caching will work the same way, and the final image will contain all of the layers from the first stage.